# Selenium Python - Getting information from Mouse Hover box

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a website I'm using Selenium to automate, and there is a mouse hover box that shows up to display relevant information for a person. Here is the HTML for the mouse hover:

```
<td align="center" nowrap="" title="Completed: 18 Omitted: 0 Remaining: 0 Date First: 09 JAN 2019 Date Last: 25 JAN 2019 ">Course Name </td>
```

I am able to get the information from this by using `driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="tblauto"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')).get_attribute('title')`, which when printed returns

Completed: 18
Omitted: 0
Remaining: 0
Date First: 09 Jan
Date Last: 25 Jan

I need to be able to pull the numbers (the dates are not relevant and if possible, could be left out of the printed list) and do simple calculations (such as adding Remaining / Completed + Omitted + Remaining) to pass on to another function as a condition of what that part of the program should. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it any more complicated than a simple text manipulation?

```
s='Completed: 18 Omitted: 0 Remaining: 0 Date First: 09 Jan Date Last: 25 Jan'
s_parts = s.split()
completed = s_parts[1]
omitted = s_parts[3]
remaining = s_parts[5]
```

Comment: I'm learning Python as I go with an actual production system at work (very small company that I volunteered to do this for), and I didn't even think of doing this. But this pretty much answers my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I had almost ignored the question, because I thought it was trivial.